# ForceType/htaccess file extension question - extensionless files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php

This is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule php4/5.c>
php_admin_flag Option
php_flag Option
php_admin_value Option
php_value Option
</IfModule>  
<Files .>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

The above code somehow works, but I'm not sure why though... I expected a 500 error. I'm OK at .htaccess, but mainly for things like blocking robots/spiders etc. rather than filetypes. The top of the file is meant for custom php.ini files (I was trying to replicate on my own Apache server as if I had no access to the proper php.ini file, like they do on web hosting companies' sites, just for added realism on my testing sites).

Although I understand how to use ForceType and SetHandler, I'm not sure how to use it for extensionless files (e.g. if I had a file called testing1, I could run it as php).

Previously I did it this way:

```
<Files testing1>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

but it became tedious doing it for every single extensionless file.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to ensure that I have extensionless files via the ForceType/SetHandler directives, but is it possible? (and is the symbol above in my first example the wildcard one, or not?)

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

`DefaultType` has been removed in Apache 2.4. Your best option is the following:

```
<Files *>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
<Files *\.*>
    ForceType None
</Files>
```

This will catch all files without an extension and process them as PHP. Then all files with an extension will be processed as normal.

Using `mod_mime_magic` is not a good choice as each file will need to be checked each time. See the [mod_mime_magic docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime_magic.html) for more info.

Comment: Remember that if your site has feature were user can upload a file, then it could cause user uploaded file to execute as PHP and then you know... BOOOOOM.

Comment: Anyone who allows for uploading of files without correctly checking the contents of the uploaded file is asking for trouble no matter what.

Comment: True, but putting that in answer as a warning might not be bad idea, as we know few people might go ahead and copy paste it.

Answer (score 4):

**For Apache 2.3 and older**, just change the `DefaultType` as follows:

```
DefaultType text/html
```

This way, every non-recognized file (including files without an extension) will be treated as HTML.

---

**For Apache 2.4 and up**, see [Tigger’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17983277/96656).

Comment: `DefaultType` has been removed (well, technically still there but does nothing but a warning) in [Apache 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#defaulttype).

Comment: @Tigger Nice! Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Extensionless files only

This solution affects only extensionless, statically served files: (credit [Eugene Kerner](https://serverfault.com/a/88449))

```
<FilesMatch "^[^.]+$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
```

#### Any unknown content

This one affects any response that would otherwise be transmitted without a `Content-Type` header.  In other words, it mimics the behaviour of the old `DefaultType` directive:

```
Header set Content-Type "application/x-httpd-php" "expr=-z %{CONTENT_TYPE}"
```

It should be possible to use `setifempty` here instead of the `-z` expression.  But it fails and overwrites the header in every response, empty or not.  I don’t know why.  [Eric Covener](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/201501.mbox/%3CCALK=YjP0PRvvx4MokxziX2qqJo_9Yos6H7dfGB72oormtc3WXA@mail.gmail.com%3E) says it’s because the `Content-Type` header isn’t added “until the very last second”.

#### Old servers only

This will fail after upgrading to 2.4: (see the [manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#defaulttype))

```
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent ages trying to resolve a similar issue where ForceType and DefaultType wouldn't work on some pages.

I found the same answer as kbk.  Edit /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and comment the lines for the Mime Magic Module:

```
<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
#   MIMEMagicFile /usr/share/magic.mime
#    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
```

After that, restart Apache.

You can find more information here: http://realtechtalk.com/HTML_files_in_Apache_still_displaying_as_raw_text_even_with_DefaultType_ForceType_etc-1752-articles

Answer (score -1):

(1) Modify .htaccess or apache2.conf or httpd.conf

Source:

- http://helpful.knobs-dials.com/index.php/Apache_config_and_.htaccess_-_semi-sorted
- http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040211102018600

Add:
    DefaultType application/octet-stream

Remove if present:
    DefaultType text/plain

Restart apache

(2) Enable mime_magic

Sources:

- http://www.wellho.net/mouth/1564_Default-file-MiMe-types-for-Apache-httpd-and-Apache-Tomcat.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_mime.html

Enable mime_magic
    $ sudo a2enmod
     -> mime_magic

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Disable a module:

```
$ sudo a2dismod
-> mime_magic
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```