# How do I tell Apache to serve files with no extension as text/html?

Tags: html, apache, mime-types, content-type

Consider a webpage, located at http://www.example.com/mypage.html

Unfortunately, someone wrongly advertises that the page's address is http://www.example.com/mypage - people visiting that URL are seeing a 404.

How can I configure Apache so visitors to mypage end up at mypage.html ?

I tried "ln -s mypage.html mypage", but the raw HTML was displayed (I guess because the file was served as text/plain)

I guess I need something in a .htaccess page but I can't work out what...

Comment: possible duplicate of [ForceType/htaccess file extension question - extensionless files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740614/forcetype-htaccess-file-extension-question-extensionless-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather redirect the user in stead of going the mime-type way:

```
Redirect 301 /mypage http://www.example.com/mypage.html
```