# How to hide PHP usage by adding extension-less file names?

Tags: php

I dont want other people to know that I'm using PHP. Is there a way to hide it by making changes to .htaccess (somethig like having extension-less file names)?

Comment: Yes you can do this with htaccess. What didn't work?

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740614/forcetype-htaccess-file-extension-question-extensionless-files/17983277

Comment: I feel bad about the fact that this question made me laugh. All I could think was poor, unloved PHP.

Comment: there are still ways to check if the server has php, regardless of  file names

Comment: @jwrush Hiding which language or server software was used is generally not a bad idea. It does not matter which language you use; there is no reason for it to be public. You would have to do more than simply hide the file extension, though.

Comment: no reason to hide it either :-)

Comment: @Dagon Yes there is. HTTP responses become smaller. Also, more importantly, the default `Server` and `X-Powered-By` headers are often a smorgasbord of information, unless you turn them off. The only people who are interested in that information are people you do not want visiting your website.

Comment: rubish, if using php gives away anything your doing it wrong.

Comment: can be done by adding AddType application/x-httpd-php .extension_name to .htaccess file ?

Comment: @Dagon It is not a way of doing security, of course, but there is absolutely no reason to advertise stuff like your PHP version, Apache version and operating system (and often various other things as well).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your web server.
For Apache you should use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: No need for mod_rewrite, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740614/forcetype-htaccess-file-extension-question-extensionless-files/17983277

Answer (score 0):

Hope its helps you

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```