# How to create a special url like 'mysite.com/adetona' for my users using PHP

Tags: php

Is there a way for me to create a special URL like `mysite.com/adetona` where `adetona` is the user's username using PHP. I know it's possible to create something like `?username=adetona' using`$_GET['username']` method but I want something more personalized than that.

How do I work my way around this in PHP?

**EDIT**

I want a way where I can grab the `username` from the URL and query so I can return the results from the database.

Comment: That's a server's configuration thing.

Comment: you can check for multiple solutions : routing, htaccess. There are not only one way, and the best - to me - is by using a routing implementation.

Comment: assuming that you are running `apache` webserver then you create some `rewrite` rules in the `.htaccess` file which effectively rewrite as you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ForceType/htaccess file extension question - extensionless files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740614/forcetype-htaccess-file-extension-question-extensionless-files)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to configure the server to make this work?

Comment: Its not as simple as `.htaccess` as you wont be able to have *other pages*. You would need to implement a check for page, check for user or 404.. so you need a front controller. Question is too broad.

Comment: Hey @LawrenceCherone, I want a situation where I can grab the 'username' from the URL and query so as to return the necessary results.

Comment: Thats fine use rewrite rules, but routing `/*` will cause problems, what about `/login` or `/register` routes?

Comment: You can use [this thread](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124269/as-basic-as-routing-in-php-can-get) as a starting point

Comment: maybe I should do something like `user/username` to avoid conflicting. what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a **.htaccess** `RewriteRule`.

I've done something similar.

`https://www.url.com/letter?id=456445` to `https://www.url.com/letter/456445`

My RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^/letter/(.*)$ beta/pages/user/letter_all.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Basically, the first part `^/letter/(.*)$` is the part that comes after your URL.

`beta/pages/user/letter_all.php?action=$1`is the path on your web-server where your file is stored.

**Your query would look something like:**

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ your/path/file.php?username=$1 [QSA]
```

### Edit

You can grab the username from the URL by using `$_GET["username"]` in PHP. It will return the value that comes after `?username=`

Comment: Thank you. I will let you know the result.

Comment: Do I have to create a `file.php`?

Comment: You need to have a file `.htaccess` in the root of your webserver. In that file are the RewriteRules. Of course you need a `php` file to handle the `$_GET["username"]` request.

Comment: The path I want to work with is `event/page.php` How do I make that work with the rewrite rules you posted above?

Comment: I'm on localhost though.

Comment: It should be in your `www/` folder of your local server. There are more things that have to be added to the `.htaccess`. But there are a lot of great tutorials out there.
Your rewrite rule would be:
`RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ event/page.php?username=$1 [QSA]`
if you place the .htaccess in the root of your project file (same folder, your `/event` is in)