# Rewrite url of php page using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have one url like this

`http://localhost/project/product_detail.php?pro_id=4&&pro_name=D.H._Tiffin_with_B.B._Packing`

I want to rewrite url like this

`http://localhost/project/product_detail/4/D.H._Tiffin_with_B.B._Packing`

Also I had changes done in `xamp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
AllowOverride All
```

I tried `.htaccess` code follow:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^project/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ project/product_detail.php?pro_id=1&&pro_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried above code, but not work.

Comment: You can do that with a combination of [`ForceType`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740614/forcetype-htaccess-file-extension-question-extensionless-files/17983277#17983277) and something like `$agrs = explode('/',$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`. No rewrite rule needed but you need to code for it from the start.

Answer (score 0):

The rewriting rule you yourself posted will never get applied to the requested URLs you cite, since the pattern won't match.

Here is something that should do what you ask:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?project/product_detail/(\d+)/(.+)$ /project/product_detail.php?pro_id=$1&&pro_name=$2 [END]
```

That rule should work likewise in the http servers host configuration or in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file). If you need to use a dynamic file then take care that the interpretation of such files is enabled and that above rule is placed in such a file located in the http hosts `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).